# How do I prevent float/decimal numbers from converting to text in Google Sheets? (iOS)

Tags: google-sheets, ios

I have a cell with the value 2.2 that is being displayed as text. I’m unable to convert the value format from text to number.

Screenshot 1 shows that cell format is number
[image: Screenshot 1]

Screenshot 2 shows that using the type formula, the cell value type is text
[image: Screenshot]

type formula info:
https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3267375

I’m currently using Google Sheets v1.2019.46202 on iOS 13.1.3

Comment: Welcome. Mobile apps are off-topic on this site. I don't know if this question could be on-topic in [apple.se].

Comment: Does this issue exist on the regular google sheets or only ios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Google sheets and the `TYPE` formula are correct giving the correct result.

Your screenshots do not complement each other.
Were they to be right, when you have the format at `Number ->1.000,12` the number returned should have been `2.20` and not `2.2` as shown here in your screenshots.

Most likely your `Locale` is wrong. Try changing it by going to `File` -> `Spreadsheet settings`.

***TIP***: *You can also test it by typing `2,2` instead. Should you test this number with `TYPE` or `ISNUMBER`* you will get the result for it being a number and not text.